# Calling the SP from MSsql issuse

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to calling the SP from MSSQL and I am getting an error:

```js
exports.ExportPropertyReport = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, APN, TimeTrend, MONTH_YEAR, lowrange, highrange) => {
    // const APN = req.body.APN;
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config, { requestTimeout: 30000 })
        //let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        let result = await pool.request()
            .input('APN', sql.Float, APN)
            .input('TimeTrend', sql.NVarChar, TimeTrend)
            .input('MONTH_YEAER', sql.NVarChar, MONTH_YEAR)
            .input('LOWRANGE', sql.VarChar, lowrange)
            .input('HighRange', sql.VarChar, highrange)
            .execute('dbo.Usp_ExportPropertyReport')

        console.log(result.recordset);

        sql.close();

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: `ExportPropertyReport called successfully`,
            result
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            "error": true,
            "message": "Error executing query"
        });
    }
});
```

error:
RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'APN'. Invalid number.
at Request.userCallback (E:\spcall\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:811:19)
at Request.callback (E:\spcall\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:205:14)
at E:\spcall\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1982:17
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
code: 'EPARAM',

I want to get the record of this stored procedure

Comment: The error seems rather self-explanatory. Also, please don't post images of errors, add their textual content to your question instead.

Comment: can you help me in this , bcoz i dont know what is self-explanatory ?

Comment: The error suggests that a parameter `J1Yr` is missing.

Comment: sorry its a different error, let me show you the error

Comment: error : RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'APN'. Invalid number.
    at Request.userCallback (E:\spcall\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:811:19)
    at Request.callback (E:\spcall\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:205:14)
    at E:\spcall\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1982:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 'EPARAM',

Comment: So make sure that the value that you're passing if valid (and, possibly, also has the correct type).

Comment: Yes datatype for APN is float in db. I am using the correct datatype

Comment: Aside... not directly related to your error message, but it's the next thing you will encounter. You should specify the correct length (based on the SQL Server-side parameter definitions) of `sql.VarChar` and `sql.NVarChar` parameters, e.g.: `sql.VarChar(30)` and `sql.NVarChar(50)` for parameters with 30 and 50 characters respectively. Failure to do so will cause Plan Cache Bloat on the SQL Server because every request will use the size of each string provided by Node, so each request potentially generates a new execution plan.

Comment: What is the data type of `APN` in Node and what is its current value? If it's a string have you tried to convert it to a float, e.g.: `parseFloat(APN) || null`?

Comment: Apn  datatype is float